# How to understand the `cmp::Reverse` Example in std docs

Tags: rust

I am confused about this example in the [std::cmp::Reverse](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/struct.Reverse.html#examples).

```rs
use std::cmp::Reverse;

let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
v.sort_by_key(|&num| (num > 3, Reverse(num)));
// v.sort_by_key(|&num| Reverse(num)); I know this means reverse the order.
assert_eq!(v, vec![3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4]);
```

How to understand the tuple `(num > 3, Reverse(num))` in this example when sorting? What does the first element in the tuple mean? I guess the tuple here means sort by the first element first, if equal, then sort by the second element. If so, any docs about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the first element in the tuple mean? I guess the tuple here means sort by the first element first, if equal, then sort by the second element. If so, any docs about this?

Yes.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.tuple.html

> The sequential nature of the tuple applies to its implementations of various traits. For example, in PartialOrd and Ord, the elements are compared sequentially until the first non-equal set is found.

Answer (score 0):

The `sort_by_key` method takes a closure and closure captures the element of the `v` by reference—which is `&num`. The later part of the closure `(num>3, Reverse(num))` is a tuple with two elements. So the closure captures each element from the `v` and applies the body of it into each element, the return value is a tuple that contains a boolean for `num>3` condition and Reverse order. The return value of the closure for the first three elements looks like `(false, Reverse(num))`, and `(true, Reverse(num))` for the last three elements.  The `v` has two sorted sequences of numbers—based on the `false` and `true` values from the tuple: the first one for the first three elements, and the second one for the last three elements of the `v`.  Both sorted sequences will be in descending order with the largest numbers coming first.  The first part of the `v` looks like `[3, 2, 1]`, and the last part looks like `[6, 5, 4]`.  Hence the final `v` looks like `[3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4]`